# Infopath 2013 - Auto Populate in User information

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have an Infopath form, with fields, Username, Email Id, Work Phone Number. I want to populate Email Id and Work Phone number of that particular user, whose name is filled in Username Column/Field. I was able to populate Current User information in to these fields by using SOAP Web Service in the past but the new requirement is to populate data of any user, when their name is filled in Username Column/Field(Not just Current user).

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the user details to InfoPath and using UPS, you should be able to populate the data!

The best blog post I found and referenced is:

https://claytoncobb.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect `soap service` to infopath
In the Data Connection Wizard,

```
URL of your site and add /_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx and click Next
```

For your reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331606/How-to-set-Current-User-Name-to-InfoPath-Person-Gr (It shows, How to connect soap service and auto populate username/login name)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/ (To auto populate WorkEmail, Manager, Title, Department)